# How to create superuser for django in docker programmatically without using the manage.py createsuperuser commad?

Tags: python, django, docker

I am a newbie to django. I have my django app running in docker, I need to create a superuser without using the createsuperuser command I tried using this code initadmin.py (shown below) but I am not able to run it in a bash file using "python manage.py initadmin". It is not working!

**initadmin.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.conf import settings


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if User.objects.count() == 0:
            for user in settings.ADMINS:
                username = 'admin'
                email = 'admin.com'
                password = 'admin'
                print('Creating account for %s (%s)' % (username, email))
                admin = User.objects.create_superuser(email=email, username=username, password=password)
                admin.is_active = True
                admin.is_admin = True
                admin.save()
        else:
            print('Admin accounts can only be initialized if no Accounts exist')
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Any better way to create superuser programmatically ?

Comment: could you add the error message you get when you try to run your management command?

Answer (score 1):

This is the definition of `create_superuser`:

<s>note that `username`,`email`,`password` are not keyword arguments, you cannot change the order when you call this method.</s>
You can change the order actually, I just tried it.

```
    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Just do this in your code:

```
User.objects.create_superuser(username, email, password)
```

`is_admin` is not an attribute of the default user model, do you mean `is_staff`?

Regardless, you don't need to set these as `create_superuser` will set them for you.
You don't need to call `save` either.

---

file structure should be like this in your case

```
PROJECT_ROOT/
    YOUR_APP/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        management/
            commands/
                initadmin.py
        tests.py
        views.py
```

Comment: thanks! I will change the order but can u tell me whether I can run it using python manage.py initadmin  .... if the folder  initadmin is having __init__.py and initadmin.py and the folder is in the same level as manage.py is!

Comment: you need to follow the structure described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/#module-django.core.management make sure you have all the blank \_\_init\_\_.py file in the right place.

Comment: i've added example

Comment: could you share your `settings.ADMINS` and your current `initadmin.py` file?